# What is "1UL << 58" converted into a decimal?

Tags: c#, decimal, converters

I have my own server on a game called conquer online. The server has character effects. Each effect has their own ID. the source is written in c#. Here is an example of the status effect

```
   public class Flags2
    {
        public const ulong

            TopPirate = 1UL << 58
     }
```

I'm not exactly sure what that would be in decimal terms? I could be completely unknowledgable about this, so hopefully im making sense

Comment: Start a test program and find out. That's the bit shift left operator.

Answer (score 4):

it's `2^58` or  `288230376151711744`

`UL` declares the number as a [unsignged long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx) value

and `<<` is a [Shift Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/a1sway8w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that  shifts the bits 58 times

from

`00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

to

`10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`